# Is JasperReports 10 times faster than Birt?

Tags: java, performance, jasper-reports, birt

I am doing an evaluation of *JasperReports* and *Birt* reporting engines.

I designed a simple report in both tools where I give 20 values to the report as parameters and fill 6 other values from an SQL selection in the report as detail relation (this means that I have many rows of them).
I programmed the creation of both reports in *Java* and the *PDF* export (I think both reporting engines use *iText*)
I measured the time each report needed. The reports are exactly the same and they are ran from the same process.
The report was ran for 10 sets of values. So I measured the time for each of the 10 reports. The result was:

**Printing Jasper reports** for 10 values. Measuring time needed.
110
109
141
125
110
125
110
125
109
110
Jasper Finished!!!

**Printing Birt reports** for 10 values. Measuring time needed.
1063
1017
1095
1079
1063
1079
1048
1064
1079
1080
Birt Finished!!!

The numbers are in msecs.

Is it possible that Jasper is 10 times faster than Birt. Am I doing something wrong with my code that slows things down for Birt? I am posting the code I used in each case:

***JasperReports:***

```
// Export Jasper report
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
JasperPrint myJasperPrint;
JRExporter myJRExporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();
try {
    myJRExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "C:/Workspace/myProject/jasperReport" + reportNr + ".pdf");
    myJasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("C:/Workspace/myProject/reports/testReport.jasper", jasperParametersMap, connection);
    myJRExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, myJasperPrint);
    myJRExporter.exportReport();
    return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
} catch (JRException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

***Birt:***

```
// Export Birt report
String format = HTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF;
EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
config.setEngineHome("C:\\Tools\\Eclipse\\plugins\\org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_4.2.2.v201302041142\\birt");
HTMLEmitterConfig hc = new HTMLEmitterConfig();
HTMLCompleteImageHandler imageHandler = new HTMLCompleteImageHandler();
hc.setImageHandler(imageHandler);
config.setEmitterConfiguration(HTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML, hc);
ReportEngine engine = new ReportEngine(config);
IReportRunnable report = null;
String reportFilepath = "C:/Workspace/EntireJ/Besuchblatt/reports/new_report.rptdesign";
HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();
options.setOutputFormat(format);
options.setOutputFileName("C:/Workspace/myProject/birtReport" + reportNr + ".pdf");
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
try {
    report = engine.openReportDesign(reportFilepath);
}
catch (EngineException e) {
    System.err.println("Report " + reportFilepath + " not found!\n");
    engine.destroy( );
    return;
}
IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(report);
task.setRenderOption(options);
task.setParameterValues(parametersMap);
try {
    task.run();
    return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
}
catch ( EngineException e1 ) {
    System.err.println( "Report " + reportFilepath + " run failed.\n");
    System.err.println( e1.toString( ) );
}
engine.destroy( );
```

**Is there a way to optimize Birt's performance in my case?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading similar discussions and completing my evaluation I think in most cases Birt is actually much slower than Jasper. There are things to do in order to make it faster, but they cost time at the moment, whereas Jasper already gives a good performance for basic reporting needs. I don't know if it could perform better than Jasper in case I set it up better or optimized the code or the report template, but in most similar cases I read on internet discussions people just accept this performance and leave it as it is. Here is an example of an issue at the openMRS which closed unsolved: https://tickets.openmrs.org/browse/BIRT-30

I hope the following image doesn't downvote me, but I was really tempted to post it. I also thought to send it to my boss as an answer to the evaluation, but I'd rather not:

[image: Jasper Birt Evaluation]

Comment: I must agree in the first part of your answer but taking the number of search results of such an insignificant query is just naive. Just browse through the first results of your search and you know what I mean...

Comment: I have never used Jasper, but I don't consider BIRT engine to be slow while doing its job (I'm using the latest 4.4.2 version). Probably Jasper is faster, could be. You could also argue the memory consumption, yes, it takes tons of memory. Anyway, it seems properer to post a good link to some serious benchmark test instead of such a silly Google search...

Comment: SSRS: 5,700,000 results - SSRS sucks: 245,000 results

Answer (score 4):

If somebody need it...

Java application on Intel i3 with 4cores 5Gb. 
Oracle database server.

Similar report template for jasper and birt that makes 20 requests to database and 20 sub-requests (subreports).

Goal:
Generate 6000 pdf documents in 30 threads ( 200 documents per thread ).

QA:

- why birt 2.6.2?

  - we are using it currently and we compared it to 4.5 - no real benefits for us.
  - birt 4.+ makes call to [getParameterMetaData()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getParameterMetaData%28%29) that is not implemented in oracle ojdbc6 and partially in ojdbc7 and just slows down execution
- why 2.6.2 patched?

  - there is a problem in birt 2.+ and 3.+ and maybe in later versions: all dataset parameters evaluated through javascript and parsed/compiled versions of those scripts are not cached. [described here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487139). Evaluated JS columns are perfectly cached in ReportRunnable.
- Why Jasper with Continuation Subreport Runner?

  - Continuation Subreport Runner [(described here)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRSubreport.html) runs all subreports in thread of the main report thread. By default jasper 6.2 uses ThreadPoolSubreportRunnerFactory that (i think by mistake) holds all previously retrieved data in the memory until full GC executed and it starts enormous number of threads.

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks for the post. You should add the conclusion though. Jasper is faster, with better heap memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you create and destroy a BIRT report engine on each run. You should initialize a report engine only once, and keep it for example in a static variable of a class for next report generations. This will be much faster

Comment: I start measuring time after the report engine object is created. The time intervals I have are only for creating and running the task.

Comment: Yes, though i noticed a report is much longer to be generated the first time it is run through a BIRT engine instance. Next runs are faster when we use the same instance, even with different report parameter values. I could not tell you why, may be the engine is caching parsed rptdesign files or something like this. You could give it a try

Comment: Actually the time intervals I posted are after the first runs. For the first run I get 4000 msec. I also tried to create the objects one time only and reuse them for each report. Still the same time, 1 sec per report.

Comment: I don't know Jasper much, but it ships with Ehcache and is probably caching recent outputs. I believe 100ms is the kind of generation time we get when a report is retrieved from a cache. It is necessary to change some parameter values between each run to compare, and include the first run.

Comment: I am trying different parameters each time of course. There is definitely no caching.

Answer (score 1):

The engine is designed to be reused. You should create it **once**, then run 10 reports. The engine loads a lot of classes when the first reports runs - later runs will be much faster. Also, the engine caches fonts. 
Your test setup is not fair.

Comment: Please read the comments under Dominique's answer. The time measurements do not contain the creation and destruction of the engine. These are not even the time intervals of the first run.

Comment: But for each run you create a new engine. From the perspective of this engine, it is thus always the very first report. It does a lot of initialization stuff then - for each run. Remember that BIRT uses a lazy loading strategy, for Java classes as well AS for resources like TTF fonts.

Comment: Please ignore the code I wrote. I cannot post the whole code I tested, where I don't create a new engine each time. I really understand what you say, but this is not the case for sure.